# Keystonejs provide me css files from wrong path. Why?

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

Any pages except `http://localhost:3000/keystone/posts/:postid` give me path to css as `http://localhost:3000/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

But on posts i have `http://localhost:3000/blog/post/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`

Why `blog/post` appearing in path on posts?

In `default.hbs` it pasted in head as

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">`

What should i look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reality, the problem was that there was not enough space on the server and I could not install node_modules because of this. So I copied them to the server from my computer.

**Do not do that.**

You must install it ONLY with `npm install`. If you can't - extend SWAP.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the relative path. Correct would be to add it to the template as

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">`

with a leading `/` in the `href` attribute.

Also: There has only ever been one type of stylesheet in the history of browsers, which is of type `text/css`, so you don't need to specify it unless you absolutely want to. :)